# Getting command line argument from a frontend

Tags: command-line, sane

I am trying to see what exact command line arguments are being sent to scanimage from xsane. I tried ltrace but couldn't find "scanimage" anywhere in the log. In general, suppose you know some GUI program is a frontend of a command line pro

Answer (score 0):

If `xsane` call `scanimage`, you will find that by replacing the `scanimage` executable by this script temporarily :

```
#!/bin/bash

exec &>/tmp/trace
echo "$0" "$@"
```

Then,

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/scanimage
xsane
cat /tmp/trace
```